# Por que esta imprimindo caracter estranho ao final da avaliação do palíndromo?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char frase[200], vetor_frase[200], palindromo[200];
    int j = strlen(frase), x = 0, p =0;

    printf("Digite uma frase:");
    gets(frase);
    for(int i = 0; i< j; i++)
    {
        if(frase[i] != ' ')
        {
            vetor_frase[x] = tolower(frase[i]);
            x++;
        }
    }
    for(int i= strlen(vetor_frase)-1; i>=0; i-- )
    {
        palindromo[p] = vetor_frase[i];
        p++;
    }
    int comparacao = strcmp(vetor_frase, palindromo);
    if (comparacao == 0)
    {
        printf(">A frase %s \n E UM PALINDROMO:%s",vetor_frase, palindromo);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("A frase %s \nNAO E PALINDROMO:%s",vetor_frase, palindromo);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em C uma string é um array de caracteres com o terminador '\0'. Faltou você  olocar este terminador ao final da montagem de vetor_frase. Idem para palindromo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo brother. vlw!.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar a função `strlen()` após o `gets(frase)`, pois fazer isso antes de ter lido a entrada faz com que a função capture um comprimento errado.

Comment: eu editei errado brother, na hora de colocar aqui. mas vlw!. era pq eu estava esquecendo o fechamento do meu vetor de caractere.